# CakePHP 2.0 + Notice (8): Undefined index: Upload [APP/Controller/UploadsController.php, line 32]

Tags: file-upload, cakephp-2.0

Im using 000webhost as a way to host my portfolio of websites. However Im getting this error thrown in which doesn't happen to me on localhost.

```
 Notice (8): Undefined index:  Upload [APP/Controller/UploadsController.php, line 32]
```

This is the code it seems to be referring to,

```
 public function add() {
            $this->render();


        if($this->request->is('post')){

            $file = $this->request->data['Upload']['file'];
                    if($this->Upload->save($this->data) && move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'],APP.'webroot/files/uploads'.DS.$this->Upload->id.'.mp4')) 
                        {
                                $this->Session->setFlash('<p class="uploadflash">The upload has been saved</p>', true);

                                $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'Uploads', 'action' => 'watch', $this->Upload->id));
                            }   else {
                        $this->Session->setFlash('<p class="loginerror">The upload could not be saved, mp4 files can be saved only.</p>', true);    

                                }

                                }
                    }
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?
Also in addition my Elements are not showing up on this online hosting either? 
I get thrown this error on the page

```
      Element Not Found: Elements/uploads/recentuploads.ctp
```

Does anyone else seem to have this problem??

Comment: What's on line 32 of UploadsController.php? Could you update your question with the debug output of `$this->request->data`?

Comment: @mensch i did the debug and it said null so Im guessing theres no errors, how comes it works fine in localhost but on the online web host its not working?

Comment: If `$this->request->data` returns null it means it doesn't contain any data, so that's not what you want. Could you provide the code of the view that contains the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further inspection I have found that the server does not allow file upload sizes to exceed 2mb, in this instance PHP throws the error above.